# Setting up grunt, bower, angular dev tools after cloning from github

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bower

I am trying to clone a project from github then set up the bower dependencies and grunt build / dev tools. When angular projects are initialy pushed to github, certain directories and files have been shed (since they are listed on the gitignore file). I am trying to figure out how to resurrect all these files necessary to locally run a project (that I find from browsing on github).

After cloning the project, I run the bower command so that it reads through bower.json:

```
% bower install
```

Then I run the grunt commands:

```
% npm install -g grunt-cli
% npm install grunt --save-dev
```

Why is the Gruntfile.js not automatically created when I run these terminal commands?

It also hangs up on an issue related to livereload but that evaporates after I run these:

```
% npm install --save-dev connect-livereload
% npm install
```

When I start a project from scratch with these yeoman and grunt commands, it automatically creates the Gruntfile.js and I can successfully get the project to auto-load in the browser:

```
% npm install -g generator-angular     
% yo angular
% bower install angular-ui
% npm install --save-dev connect-livereload
% npm install
% grunt test
% grunt server
% grunt
```

But I am trying to master the technique of cloning a project from github and then setting up the project locally. I am close but currently I am also experiencing an issue with a missing Gruntfile.js. I would be very grateful for any direction you could provide. All the best,

Ben

Comment: not answer to your question, but you can find it useful: http://yeoman.io/

Comment: did you ever figure out a good approach ?

Answer (score 6):

### Using Yeoman

You don't need to clone the project from GitHub.

You simply need to make a new (clean) project directory.

```
cd /new/project/directory
```

(Optional) Update NPM

```
npm update -g npm
```

Install angular scaffold

```
npm install -g generator-angular
```

Run yeoman scaffold

```
yo angular
```

Fire up a server

```
grunt server
```

Start building your app, perhaps with Angular sub-generators

```
yo angular:controller myController
yo angular:directive myDirective
yo angular:filter myFilter
yo angular:service myService
```

### Using bower to install front-end dependencies

#### Search for repos to install

```
bower search dep-name
```

or, http://sindresorhus.com/bower-components/

#### See what all has been installed

```
bower list
```

or, see your `bower.json` file

#### Installing dependencies

```
bower install dep-name
```

or, add it to `bower.json` file then simply run `bower install`**(Preferred)**

## Most of all, Read Documentation

1. [Yeoman Getting Started](http://yeoman.io/gettingstarted.html)
2. [Bower](http://bower.io/)
3. [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started)

I would recommend reading through Yeoman first. Get the hang of it, then move on to the other docs once you need more advanced customization for your project. Generally, the Yeoman docs cover bower and grunt well as it relates to your Yeoman project.

Comment: I need to clone the project from GitHub because I want to run code that someone else has developed. This question is not related to how to initially set up a project.

Comment: Is it a front-end project? Something you can find in `bower search` or http://sindresorhus.com/bower-components/

Comment: After reading you edits, it seems like a problem specific to a certain repo. Mind sharing the repo?

Comment: I don't have a specific in mind per se but this is one I've been practicing with this morning: https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed

Comment: Just trying to understand the "general" process of learning about a new technique, search for it on github, pulling it down and actually being able to run it locally

Comment: I have the same problem: I install yo:angular start work then push it to a git repository. Then, in another machine, I want to start working. I clone the repo but I can't do it work in this new machine

Answer (score 3):

I get it working after do the following:

```
brew install nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

It will install nvm then you can controll your npm version (may you have problem with this with yo:angular project)

Then you should make sure that you are using npm 0.10

```
nvm install 0.10
nvm use 0.10
```

To avoid problems with previous npm installations cached you should use:

```
sudo npm -g cache clean
```

Now you are ready to get your yo:angular project working in your machine:

```
git clone <yourproject>

cd <your-project-directory>

npm install
```

It will install grunt and karma for you, then you should install all bower packages before start your dev server:

```
bower install
```

Then, finally, your project are done to be working so you can use:

```
grunt serve
```

:)